# How to manually mount a partition?

Tags: mount

There are many questions on automatically mounting or problems encountered during mounting that I've read here. But none on how to manually mount a partition.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The first step is to list all your partitions to find the one you want to mount:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME        FSTYPE  LABEL                    SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                         14.4G 
├─sdb4      iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64   1.4G /media/rick/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64
├─sdb2                                         1M 
├─sdb5      ext4    casper-rw                6.4G /media/rick/casper-rw
├─sdb3      vfat    usbboot                  244M 
└─sdb1      ntfs    usbdata                  6.4G /media/rick/usbdata
sr0                                         1024M 
sda                                        931.5G 
├─sda4      ntfs    WINRETOOLS               450M 
├─sda2                                       128M 
├─sda5      ntfs    Image                   11.4G 
├─sda3      ntfs    HGST_Win10               919G /mnt/d
└─sda1      vfat    ESP                      500M 
nvme0n1                                      477G 
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4    NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0        44.6G /
├─nvme0n1p3                                   16M 
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                             450M 
├─nvme0n1p8 ext4    Ubuntu18.04             23.7G 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap    Linux Swap               7.9G [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs    NVMe_Win10             391.2G /mnt/c
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                              99M /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs    Shared_WSL+Linux           9G /mnt/e
```

For this example, we will mount `nvme0n1p8` which has the label `Ubuntu18.04`. To credit sources, we'll be following this [article](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/mount-partitions-in-terminal-fstab/) as a
guide.

### Create mount point directory

The next step is to create a directory under `/mnt` that the newly mounted partition will be referred to as:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/Ubuntu18.04
```

### Mount the partition to the new directory

The final step is to mount the partition to the new directory:

```
$ sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/Ubuntu18.04
/dev/nvme0n1p8 mounted on /mnt/Ubuntu18.04.
```

Notice we prepend `/dev/` to the names provided by `lsblk` above.

Now let's see what we've just mounted:

```
$ ll /mnt/Ubuntu18.04
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Apr 26 17:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Apr 27 20:51 ../
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Apr 26 17:00 lost+found/
```

`lost_found` is needed for `fschk` command (File System check). It is automatically created and normally we don't have to "fiddle" with it.

### Unmount the partition

When we are finished we can unmount the partition using the `-l` parameter which safely unmounts the partition:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p8 -l
```

---

## Script method

A script to mount partition is available in this answer:

- [Mount Debian install as USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064537/mount-debian-install-as-usb-drive/1064681#1064681)

This screen appears tailored to your unique machine environment:

[image: mount-menu 1.png]

Answer (score 3):

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

would be enough in most cases. `-t auto` is used as default here which uses heuristics to find the filesystem type:

> If no -t option is given, or if the auto type is specified, mount will
> try to guess the desired type. ([Source](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount))

If you work with sensitive data specifiy the filesystem type rather explicitely:

> Warning: the probing uses a heuristic (the presence of appropriate
> 'magic'), and could recognize the wrong filesystem type, possibly with
> catastrophic consequences. If your data is valuable, don't ask mount
> to guess. ([Source](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount))

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Comment: Quick note (because it just happened to me) - make sure to add a mount target in `/mnt`. If you have `/mnt/fs1` and `/mnt/fs2` - running that above command may eliminate those two other points where `/mnt` is actually `sda1`. So I'd use `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1_label ` instead. (If it does happen, unmounting it should return everything back to where it was.)