# How do I mount second internal hard drive?

Tags: mount

My system isn't recognizing my second hard drive (sbd) When I try to mount it:

~ $ sudo mount /dev/sbd /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sbd does not exist

Please help.

Disk /dev/sdb: 93.2 GiB, 100030242816 bytes, 195371568 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier: F10F0906-7838-4896-ACD9-BC3411C1D63B

Comment: This looks like a simple typo. I am pretty sure it has to be `/dev/sdb` instead.

Comment: You are right; sometimes I can't see for looking! I corrected the typo a recieved this message: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: You do not mount drives like sdb, but mount partitions like sdb1. You have created partition(s) on sdb? What format are partitions on sdb? is it an internal or external drive.

Comment: Always post terminal output in original question, so you can keep format. Posted in comment it loses formatting and often is unreadable.

Comment: Manual mounting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition

Comment: the disk has no label, also I would like to mount it as /home if that is at all possible.

Comment: Unless it was formatted, either as an entire drive (not recommended) or with partition(s) and formats for each partition, you could not have copied standard data to it. You may have use dd or some tools that copy bits not files. So what format is sdb? Or how did you copy data to it?

Comment: It was automatically mounted as a drive when I was using elementary OS, but I have since switched to Kde Plasma