# Moving files to External hardrive with Terminal

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I was about to move my files to an external hardrive and install a new linux distro when (in literally the worst timing ever) my computer died and now the desktop is non existant.

Is it possible to move my files (which are all in one folder on my desktop) to my external hardrive?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to login to the console with `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1` or `ctrl`+`alt`+`f3` I think depending on your Ubuntu version. Then you'll need to `mount` the external hard drive. Finally use the `cp` command to copy files. You might want to use the `mkdir` command first to make a directory on the external device to hold the files.

Comment: My big issue is I have no idea how to find the directory of my external drive

Comment: Issue `lsblk` command which will show your drive name (e.g. `/dev/sdb`), mount it then.

Comment: Perfect, how do I mount my drive sdc?

Comment: [How to manually mount a partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition)