# Unable to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on separate drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my main SSD and windows on my secondary hard drive for games. After a lot of hassle with trying to preserve my original ubuntu I bend the knee to installing Ubuntu after windows.
Sadly grub isn't able to find my windows on the second hard drive.

- Fast boot is disabled
- Secure boot is disabled
- Os-prober returns nothing
- Update-grub does not add my windows install
- adding a custom entry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom results in a /bootmgr not found error

I'm at a loss, everything I could find online I've tried. My motherboard is an Asus Maximus ranger VII if that helps with certain bios settings that I need to tweak.

blkid output:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="771f3eb4-1d56-46be-a608-c63bbf6d1782" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e4ef4311-01"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d55691bd-0fb2-4b58-ab7e-a352a9397d59"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="A2D2-0615" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b65b936b-123d-44f1-85bb-9121d581e45d"
/dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="3942ab5f-23b8-475b-ba3d-c08004d620f3"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="E2B2DFFAB2DFD0E1" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e1de24ed-0031-4b83-8b35-e8c7ec87f858"
```

Comment: You need to install both systems in the same mode. Make sure all the drives are GPT and that you're booting the installers in UEFI mode. In this mode the order is irrelevant. That's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual Boot on seperate drives - best configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

## Mount partition

First ensure you've [mounted your window's partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition/1029041#1029041):

```bash
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME        FSTYPE  LABEL                    SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                         14.4G 
├─sdb4      iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64   1.4G /media/rick/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64
├─sdb2                                         1M 
├─sdb5      ext4    casper-rw                6.4G /media/rick/casper-rw
├─sdb3      vfat    usbboot                  244M 
└─sdb1      ntfs    usbdata                  6.4G /media/rick/usbdata
sr0                                         1024M 
sda                                        931.5G 
├─sda4      ntfs    WINRETOOLS               450M 
├─sda2                                       128M 
├─sda5      ntfs    Image                   11.4G 
├─sda3      ntfs    HGST_Win10               919G /mnt/d
└─sda1      vfat    ESP                      500M 
nvme0n1                                      477G 
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4    NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0        44.6G /
├─nvme0n1p3                                   16M 
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                             450M 
├─nvme0n1p8 ext4    Ubuntu18.04             23.7G 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap    Linux Swap               7.9G [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs    NVMe_Win10             391.2G /mnt/c
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                              99M /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs    Shared_WSL+Linux           9G /mnt/e
```

## 30_os-prober

Make sure your `30_os-prober` is marked as executable as shown below:

```bash
$ ll /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11736 Jun 29  2018 /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober*
```

---

## TL;DR

Most people recommend switching from the default Intel RST to AHCI. I've found that both work however.

I did change BIOS to not reload from hard disk each boot which saved 4 seconds or so. I also changed BIOS to not read from NIC cards which saved a few seconds. BIOS POST used to take about 16 seconds and I trimmed it down to 5 seconds. Still too long I think because Dell Inspiron 17R 7720SE is only a second or two.

In BIOS make sure TPM and secure boot is turned off. Also you might want to follow `boot-repair` suggestion to move partition to front of disk:

```bash
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 43583516-680C-4323-A4B1-592DF4DEEB70

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2     923648    1126399    202752    99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1126400    1159167     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1159168  762818491 761659324 363.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5  819851264  821610495   1759232   859M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6  821610496  916246527  94636032  45.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7  916246528  964739071  48492544  23.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8  964739072  983709695  18970624     9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p9  983709696 1000214527  16504832   7.9G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p10 762818560  819851263  57032704  27.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8BEC7AEB-4576-42B0-8A8A-D40779A80126

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047    1024000  500M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1026048    1288191     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1288192 1928626175 1927337984  919G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1928626176 1929547775     921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  1929547776 1953523711   23975936 11.4G Windows recovery environment
```

As you can see both Windows 10 on SDD and HDD appear:

[image: grub.gif]