# Ubuntu 19: How do I mount an old HDD?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 19.04, ownership

I recently bought an SSD where I installed Ubuntu 19. I decided to use my old HDD as extra storage. However, the mounted HDD is unusable as it requires root access. I can't change it from the properties since it states that I am not the owner of it. Rookie here.

Update:
Followed the instruction on this link:[How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition/1029041#1029041)
,
this is what I got after entering the last step.

```
$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /mnt/storagedrive
mount: /mnt/storagedrive: /dev/sdb1 already mounted on /hdd.
```

Comment: Follow this answer and then post what you entered and the error messages received: [How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition/1029041#1029041)

Comment: So the old drive is already mounted at /hdd, but with root only access? Try `sudo ls -l /hdd`

Comment: Which file system is used on that partition? Please add output of `mount | grep /dev/sdb1` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1174753/edit) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `sudo gnome-disks` to reconfigure the old disk. See https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks

Comment: Please fill in the details. The answer should be present here, in this posting.