# How to mount ssd partition?

Tags: mount, drive

My laptop contains an 512gb ssd of which i have made 3 partitions. The C drive has windows os installed, the d drive has my files and the other drive is where ubuntu 18.04 is installed. Every time i try to mount it it shows " can't find in /etc/fstab". 
I tried

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/Dvol
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/Dvol
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition) Let me know if this doesn't solve the problem and I'll retract my close vote. Thank you.