# How to create a permanet shortcut folder without occupying space on both partition

Tags: dual-boot, samba, windows-10, shortcuts

I am using a dual partition on my laptop, in particular I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I would like to share a folder between the 2 partitions, but what I found is to use a software called Samba.

What I didn't understand is that this method is going to occupy space on both partitions and if this requires the internet connection.

I forgot to introduce that from Ubuntu if I surf in files/other locations/windows etc I can find all the files that I need, but it's very long to do each time.

Secondly I created a shortcut but it is not permanent, it disappears when I power off the computer.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to this community! Please consider revising your text, enumerating clearly what your problems are and what question regards which. This will make it easier for readers to provide the suggestions requested accurately and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Samba is to connect *different computer* over the network. This situation is not applicable for you, because your partitions exist on the same computer.

What you are looking for is to have your second partition (the Windows partition) automatically mounted after startup.

By default, your Windows partition is not connected when you start Ubuntu. You can, however, easily connect it by clicking the icon of the partition in the left pane of "Files", the file manager (a.k.a. nautilus). For practical purposes, this could be enough. It takes one click each time before you can access the files.

However, you can also have that Windows partition mounted automatically during startup. You can use the utility "Disks" for that. After that, the partition will automatically be available in the folder you indicate as mount point.

For this to successfully work each time, you must make sure that your Windows partition is **clean** when Ubuntu starts. To make sure it is clean, you need to turn of "Fast start" in Windows. This way, you have Windows shut down completely each time. Only then will it fully close the ntfs partition, so Ubuntu can mount it.

Once set up, your Windows disk will automatically be available within the Ubuntu system. Any shortcuts you create will work right after the start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vanadium, what happen to windows if I turn off the 'Fast start'? After the windows partition is mounted automatically can I create a permanent shortcut from windows desktop to ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Windows will start up slightly slower. Because the windows disk is mounted, any shortcut will immediately work. I added the latter to the answer.

Comment: I turned off fast startup in windows, then it seems that the windows partition is already mounted., because if I go in nautilis/other locations there is the Windows partition /dev/nvm.. with the 'unmount symbol' on the right. Therefore I created the shortcut using the ctrl+shift and I moved the the 'link to namefolder' to the desktop of ubuntu. Then I turned off the computer and when I switched it on the folder had a red cross on it

Comment: That is because what I wrote in my answer applies.

Comment: I tried to use the 'Disk' to mount it and I succed but it didn't work well at the end, instead using this tutorial (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition) it works. thanks

Comment: Editing fstab also is the way I prefer to do it.

Comment: It was workin well, but this morning the linked folder started to be corrupted and in nautilus if I go in other locations on the Windows partition there is now a prohibition sign. What can I do?