# How to mount another HDD data drive automatically

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, budgie

> I have installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04. In my laptop, there is ssd a for
>   operating system on which I have installed Ubuntu and another 1TB HDD
>   drive for data. The drive is shown in the Disks app. I have searched
>   for solution in which I have to make changes in Edit Mount options to
>   disable it. But in my case the option is greyed out.
>
> I have tried another way by using command `sudo ldmtool create all`.
>   Which allow me to access the data drive. but it does not mount
>   automatically. There was another command which was supposed to mount
>   `sudo mount /dev/mapper/ldm_vol_SPONS_SERVER-Dg0_Volume1 /destination path`. 
>   But it did not work.

[image]

Comment: Did you turn off the "user Session Defaults" to allow changes to the greyed-out information? (Assuming you have already  clicked on the additional options icon, then "edit mount options").

Comment: Yes, I  had turn off the "user session defaults". But after reboot it goes back to previous settings and there is no change for mounting disk.

Comment: give this a try please https://superuser.com/questions/912070/windows-spanned-disk-ldm-automount

Answer (score 0):

The hard drives (or partitions) that you setup in the gui interface of the disk manager automatically get added to /etc/fstab to be mounted automatically at boot. You can also click the settings icon next to the minus icon and that will give you a menu where you can click an option if you want that partition to be mounted at boot. Also, if you are talking about another partition and you can't mount it through the gui you can see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition) on how to manually mount it. Once you have you can go back and make it mount at boot.

Comment: I tried with ```$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT```. The outbut was ```sdb                        931.5G 
├─sdb1                         1M 
├─sdb2                       127M 
└─sdb3                     931.4G 
```. So this is the partition I want to mount. I tried to mount with ```sudo mkdir /mnt/sdb3```. I check in the file manager, the folder was there sdb3 but it was empty.

Comment: Are that all the commands you entered to try and mount it? If so then you also have to put the mount command to mount the drive (or partition). Typically you would mount them with a command like this```sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/Ubuntu18.04```