# Can't see the windows partitions from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, disk

I have a Dell Latitude 3500 with a 1GB HDD and Window 10 on it. I added a 500GB NVME drive which I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on. Ubuntu did not see the Windows 10 installation but did see the `EFI` boot partition and `GRUB` allows me to boot into Windows or Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           786M  2.1M  783M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  458G   32G  404G   8% /
tmpfs           3.9G   44M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop0       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop2      276M  276M     0 100% /snap/octave/29
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop5       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop6      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop7      2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop8       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/sda1       146M   46M  101M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           786M   16K  786M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           786M   28K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

GParted shows `sda1` to `sda4` with `sda3` being the main Windows partition. Can anyone tell me how to mount `sda3` so that I can view it in Nautilus?

Comment: I think you mean t to say `1 TB` hard drive and not `1 GB`?

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off, it sets hibernation flag which prevents normal mount. You can force read only mount. Note that Windows turns fast start up back on with some updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

Dell laptops come with BitLocker enabled from the factory and it causes no end of problems.  Loads of reports of people unable to access their data because of faults with it. The encrypted drive meant that Ubuntu could not read.

I disabled BitLocker in Windows (which took forever) and now the OS drive appears in the "Other Locations" part of Nautilus.

Comment: Please don't ask a question in the Answers section. If you want to add more info to your question, then 'edit' your question and update it. If you have a separate issue, ask a new question. If you want to ask for clarification from an answerer, then use the 'add a comment' below that specific answer. I have removed the question part this time.

Answer (score 0):

Please open "files" app (by default in ubuntu). Then click on " + Other Locations ". There you'll be able to see your windows partition as shown in the image.
[image]

In the image, "307 GB Volume -- /dev/sda2" is my unmounted Windows partition. Clicking on which, it will get mounted and you'll be able to access it on nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

The `df` utility only shows mounted partitions:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs            784M  1.7M  783M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6    45G   35G  8.0G  82% /
tmpfs            3.9G  363M  3.5G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p10   27G   22G  3.9G  85% /mnt/clone
/dev/nvme0n1p4   364G  179G  185G  50% /mnt/c
/dev/nvme0n1p2    95M   33M   63M  35% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p7    23G   19G  3.1G  86% /mnt/old
/dev/nvme0n1p8   9.1G  1.9G  7.3G  20% /mnt/e
/dev/sda3        920G   42G  878G   5% /mnt/d
tmpfs            784M  140K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Using the `lsblk` utility you can see all partitions:

```
$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1      259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p9  259:9    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p7  259:7    0  23.1G  0 part /mnt/old
├─nvme0n1p5  259:5    0   859M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   450M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p8  259:8    0     9G  0 part /mnt/e
├─nvme0n1p10 259:10   0  27.2G  0 part /mnt/clone
├─nvme0n1p6  259:6    0  45.1G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0 363.2G  0 part /mnt/c
└─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb            8:16   1  58.6G  0 disk 
sda            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda4         8:4    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda2         8:2    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda5         8:5    0  11.4G  0 part 
├─sda3         8:3    0   919G  0 part /mnt/d
└─sda1         8:1    0   500M  0 part
```

In my case I've already mounted Windows partitions as `/mnt/c`, `/mnt/d` and `/mnt/e`. Therefore they can be selected from Nautilus. Using the `lsblk` output above you can use it see your Windows partitions you want to mount. Then see this answer:

- [How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition/1029041#1029041)