# Not able to mount the disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu

I recently I installed Ubuntu, but I am unable to mount the disk on it.
I run the following command to mount the disk.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /disk20
```

mount: /disk20: mount point does not exist.

Results of `sudo fdisk -l` :

```
/dev/sda6       1064134656 1073895423   9760768   4.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris 
/dev/sda7       1024002048 1064132607  40130560  19.1G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda8       1073897472 1159673855  85776384  40.9G 83 Linux   
/dev/sda9       1159675904 1257330687  97654784  46.6G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda10      1257332736 1354985471  97652736  46.6G 83 Linux   
/dev/sda11      1354987520 1550305279 195317760  93.1G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition)

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing this problem because you are trying to mount the volume to a directory that does not exist. In order to be able to mount there, you must create the directory first. So in the case of your desired mountpoint, `/disk20`, you would run this command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /disk20
```

This will create the directory. Now you can mount the partition as you did before:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /disk20
```

Do note, however, that creating your own directories in the root (/) folder is generally not recommended (although shouldn't be harmful). Instead of mounting to `/disk20`, it would be more ideal to mount to a mountpoint that is designed for mounting partitions. One example of this is the `/mnt` directory. Assuming this directory is empty, run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
```

Another advantage of mounting to `/mnt` is that the directory already exists so you won't need to manually create it with `mkdir -p` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read & write to your disk create a directory at /mnt/myDisk. Set up the user mode to read an write:

```
sudo chmod 666 /mnt/myDisk
```

then

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/myDisk
```

Should work now