# Nautilus hides my second SSD

Tags: mount, nautilus

Why does Nautilus keep hiding my second SSD? It's formatted as ext4 for additional storage, and it's also set to automount. The problem is that sometimes it's visible, sometimes not. This Ubuntu 21.10.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=234baac4-67d8-447f-8ef8-a28d8304f83b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
#UUID=3EA2-036B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=3EA2-036B  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

[image]

Comment: What **should** it look like in Nautilus? All I see is "62 GB Volume". Is that it? What is "Munene files"? Show us your /etc/fstab.

Comment: 62gb volume is my flash drive. i have no problem with that. the problem s munene files ssd

Comment: As requested, please edit your question and show us /etc/fstab.

Comment: <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=234baac4-67d8-447f-8ef8-a28d8304f83b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
#UUID=3EA2-036B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=3EA2-036B  /boot/efi       vfat    default

Comment: /etc/fstab should have been an edit to your question, not into the comments... as you can see it's terrible to try and read it there. Anyway, why is **#UUID=3EA2-036B /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1** commented out, and replaced with an invalid **UUID=3EA2-036B /boot/efi vfat default**? Where is your mount for "Munene files"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually mount a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition)