# After installing Ubuntu 22.04, unable to access a drive used on Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, format

My Windows 10 installation became corrupted and I couldn't repair it, so yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04.

However, I am unable to access a disk that was labeled "D" on Windows.

In the past, I've formatted Windows' C drive and the D drive was always safe and accessible. I thought if I installed Ubuntu where C was located, the data on D would be safe and it would not have been deleted.  This is important data.

How do I access the files on this disk?

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0 998,6M  1 loop /snap/android-studio/123
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0  18,4M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/30
loop3    7:3    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
loop4    7:4    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop5    7:5    0  63,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop6    7:6    0  82,9M  1 loop /snap/discord/141
loop7    7:7    0 163,3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1635
loop8    7:8    0 176,9M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1810
loop9    7:9    0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop10   7:10   0 400,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop11   7:11   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop12   7:12   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop13   7:13   0 174,7M  1 loop /snap/opera/199
loop14   7:14   0 389,7M  1 loop /snap/qt515-core20/25
loop15   7:15   0  45,9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop16   7:16   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop17   7:17   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778
loop18   7:18   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop19   7:19   0  17,2M  1 loop /snap/whatsie/127
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  58,9G  0 part /media/mhbd2009/22.04
├─sda5   8:5    0   5,8G  0 part /media/mhbd2009/WINDRIVER
└─sda6   8:6    0  53,9G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931,5G  0 part
```

Comment: @RishonJR Ubuntu has supported mounting/reading/writing NTFS natively for years now and 22.04 already has `ntfs-3g` installed. OP -- Drive letters like "C" and "D" are Windows designations and have nothing to do with the volume itself and these designations are irrelevant to Ubuntu, so if you're looking for "D" you're not going to find it.  What happens *exactly* when you try to mount the drive?  FYI, data that isn't backed up is never "safe", and "important" data that never gets backed up will eventually be lost, whether it's due to hardware failure or user error

Comment: @mhbd2009 did you run a standard install or a minimum install?

Comment: One imagines you are trying to locate files on sdb2? If so, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition