I can't use HDD directory, probably, HDD mounting mistake
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTC. I have HDD and SDD.
The problem is I can't store files on HDD directory. I think I mounted HDD directory wrong. I tried to figure it out on my own, but I got even more confused.
Could you please advise me how to correct the mistake? Which information do I need to post?

You have to create partition with Linux format (preferred), create mount point, mount partition, and give yourself ownership & permission to use that mount. If permanent drive better to edit fstab with mount, so on reboot its mounted. You can manually mount also. Best mount parameters vary by format of partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

What do you mean by "direction"?

I corrected the typo. Directory, not direction.

@oldfred Thank you for your answer. I will study it.
