# Force mount sd card partitions after `dd`

Tags: mount, raspberrypi, sd-card, dd

When I write the Raspberry Pi image to the SD card on `Ubuntu` using `dd`, I need to remove the card and plug it in again in order for it's images to be automatically mounted to e.g. `/media/$(whoami)/boot/`. So that I can `touch /media/$(whoami)/boot/ssh` to enable SSH.

Is there a way to force this auto-mounting of the partitions after `dd`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/397190/usb-drive-are-not-mounted-automatically check here

Comment: You can try with `sudo partprobe` from a terminal window.

Comment: @sarru1291 what exactly are you suggesting to check in the referenced question?

Comment: @sudodus `partprobe` doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @Janos,  Unfortunately, sometimes with memory cards it seems that the only way is to unplug and plug back in order to make the kernel recognize the new partition table in the card and mount the partition(s) found.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using `eject -t` re-mounts everything, as if the card has been ejected and re-inserted:

```bsh
sudo eject -t /dev/sdc
```